# Excel equivilant of java's String.contains(String otherString)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell that has a fairly archaic String. (It's the mana cost of a Magic: the Gathering spell.) Examples are `3g`, `2gg`, `3ur`, and `bg`. There are 5 possible letters (`g w u b r`). I have 5 columns and would like to count at the bottom how many of each it contains. So my spreadsheet might look like this

```
  A                   B        C  D  E  F  G
 +--------------------------------------------
1|Name                Cost     G  W  U  B  R
2|Centaur Healer      1gw      1  1  0  0  0
3|Sunspire Griffin    1ww      0  1  0  0  0 // just 1, even though 1ww
4|Rakdos Shred-Freak  {br}{br} 0  0  0  1  1
```

Basically, I want something that looks like `=if(contains($A2,C$1),1,0)` and I can drag it across all 5 columns and down all 270 some cards. (Those are actual data, by the way. It's not mocked :-) .)

In Java I would do this:

```
String[] colors = { "B", "G", "R", "W", "U" };
for(String color : colors) {
    System.out.print(cost.toUpperCase().contains(color) ? 1 : 0);
    System.out.print("\t");
}
```

Is there something like this in using Excel 2010.

I tried using `find()` and `search()` and they work great if the color exists. But if the color doesn't exist, it returns `#value` - so I get `1  1  #value  #value  #value` instead of `1 1 0 0 0` for, example, Centaur Healer (row 2). The formula used was `if(find($A2,C$1) > 0, 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("text", A1)), "false", "true")` should work.

If you need to use wildcards, you can try `search` instead of `find`.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, except I used `search` instead of `find`. Still unsure what the difference is, but it works for my purposes.

Comment: From what I can see and as I mentioned above, wildcard support seems to be the chief (only?) difference between the two. BTW, another variant that might come in handy: `=IFERROR(FIND("text", A1), "error")`

Comment: In addition to wildcard support, `SEARCH` is not case sensitive, while `FIND` is.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I believe you are looking for [find()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php).

```
FIND( substring, string, [start_position] )
```

Comment: I tried `find` but if it doesn't exist, I don't have a value to compare it to. Instead of `0 1 0 0 0` I get `#VALUE 1 #VALUE #VALUE #VALUE`

Comment: @corsiKa: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513795/excel-2010-check-if-sub-string-value-in-cell-match-with-other-string-from-range as you might be able to pull something off by using [`IFERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx). Sometimes #VALUE could also mean the column isn't wide enough to display it...

Comment: Tom that's excellent. I did `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(K$1,$E2)>0,1,0),0)` and it worked perfectly. (the `K$1,$E2` there is the equivalent of `$A2,C$1` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

`=N(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(C$1,$B2))))`

Comment: btw the advantage with search is that you don't have to bother about the case...
And if you want to change later that 1 and 0 to something else, this is better: =IF(ISERR(SEARCH(C$1,$B2)),0,1)